# Can I ask a question about how to publish my local website online on DA?

Tags: support

I've built a Drupal website in WAMP and I'd now like to publish it online. However, I've no idea how to do that. Is it permitted to ask this on Drupal Answers? If not, where can I find more information about this?

Comment: you need to buy a domain and hosting to publish your website world wide.

Comment: I think you can ask in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Even if general answer is "no", +1 from me here - thank you for asking :) @Bala webmasters will not be glad to answer things that should be covered by hosts's documentation. And no stack site will allow "shopping" for hosting. So *some* things can be asked on Server Fault or Webmasters, but one should really read their help centers before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a specific question about something Drupal is stopping you from doing in regard to your hosting, then yes, that can be asked here.

If the question is literally "how do I deploy a website from local to live?", then no; that would be too broad for any Stack Exchange site, and most of what you'd need to know is not relevant to Drupal. You need to:

- Get a host that meets minimum requirements
- Get a database
- Get your files and database backup from local to live

Only after that does anything remotely related to Drupal get involved (unless you're deploying with Drush or something else Drupal-y, but obviously if you are you'd be asking a specific question about that tool). Everything else is stuff we can't help with here unfortunately.